# Detecting collision with known size and position on a rectangle

Tags: math, collision, game-development

I want to detect collision between two rectangles where I know the size and position for both of them. I tried this c# code inside my "brick" class that uses the center of the player and the brick as reference:

```
public bool IsTouchingPlayer(Player player) 
{
    return (player.xPos > xPos - (width / 2) && player.xPos < xPos + (width / 2)) &&
    (player.yPos > yPos - (height / 2) && player.yPos < yPos + (height / 2));
}
```

But sadly, this only accounts for the center of the player colliding with the brick; I think it's safe to say this is a problem.

If you need more info let me know.

Comment: you're not taking into account the player's hitbox size. Your player xPos is a single point. If you want the size of the player, you need to take into account the "rectangle" or "polygon" that contains the player, and check if any of the collision spaces overlap

Comment: Some times is more easy to check 'not touching' and negate it. Not touching is easy to thing: is over or at right or at left or below.

Comment: @RobertMennell Yes, excactly. I just have no clue how to go about this

Comment: You merely need to check if any one of the vertices of the player's hitbox is inside the brick's hitbox.

Comment: @RobertMennell I believe your solution makes assumptions on movement speed. If at the relative speed of both rectangles is near their sizes you can have a collision without any vertex of one of the boxes being within the other, if it completly overlaps.

Comment: @Yunnosch how do you mark inclusiveness with within? that might be the language I'm looking for

Comment: Use pen and paper. Draw rectangles. All cases you want to cover. Especially a small one within a large one. Write down the coordinates of all vertexes of your examples. Then find the caculcation of each of those xcoordinates from the values you have (center coords, width, height, of both boxes). Look at all of that. If you find a way to detect overlap or total overlap by looking at the vertexes, the coordinates, or the calculcation you are done. If you can't do as much of that and add it to your question. Maybe some ascii art of rectangles, with coordinate examples and calculations ...

Comment: @RobertMennell Above comment addresses you as much as OP.

Answer (score 0):

Grow one rectangle with other sizes in all directions.
And check if the center position of the other is contained in the enlarged rectangle.

This is easy, especially if both rectangles are Axis-Aligned.

Comment: It seems that, currently you already have "rectangle vs point" implementation, so, this way will be able to be achieved with a bit of code change.  (if you are dealing with Axis-Aligned rects)